# Trouble with "For-Loop range must have an 'iterator()' method" and JSON issues

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am teaching myself Kotlin and android dev. So, i'm sure most of my issue is lack of knowledge, but i've been hung up on this part for day or two. I think my issue is partly my JSON query, and mostly my rookieness.

In my for loop below, I'm getting the following error from the IDE "For-Loop range must have an 'iterator()' method". This is in regards to 'cycloneList' in: for(stormInfo in cycloneList)

I've linked my "dummy" JSON data I'm using can be found here: https://api.myjson.com/bins/19uurt to save a bit of space here in the question.

**Problem code**

```
`var cycloneList = response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.stormInfo?.get(0) 

if (cycloneList != null) {
            for (stormInfo in cycloneList) { <<--Problem
                val newCyclone = "Name: ${cycloneList.stormName}"
                cycloneStrings.add(newCyclone)
            }
        }`
```

**FULL CODE**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //creates a new CycloneRetriever object from CycloneHelp.kt
    var retriever = CycloneRetriever()

    val callback = object : Callback<Cyclones> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Cyclones>?, response: Response<Cyclones>?) {
            println("Got a response!")

            var cycloneList = response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.stormInfo?.get(0)

            var cycloneStrings = mutableListOf<String>()

            if (cycloneList != null) {
                for (stormInfo in cycloneList) { //TODO Figure this out!!
                    val newCyclone = "Name: ${cycloneList.stormName}"
                    cycloneStrings.add(newCyclone)
                }
            }

            var layoutMovieListView = movieListView

            var movieListAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    cycloneStrings)

            layoutMovieListView.adapter = movieListAdapter
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Cyclones>?, t: Throwable?) {
            println("The thing, it failed!")
        }
    }
    retriever.getCyclones(callback)
}
```

I'm using Retrofit to access/handle JSON data

**Retrofit JSON code**

```
interface WeatherWunderGroundAPI {
    @GET("bins/19uurt")

    fun getCyclones() : Call<Cyclones>
}

class Cyclones(val currenthurricane: CurrentHurricane)
class CurrentHurricane(val stormInfo: List<StormInfo>)
class StormInfo(val stormName: String)

class CycloneRetriever {
    val service : WeatherWunderGroundAPI

    init {
        val = retrofitCyclone 
                Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()

        service = retrofitCyclone.create(WeatherWunderGroundAPI::class.java)
    }

    fun getCyclones(callback: Callback<Cyclones>) {
        val call = service.getCyclones()
        call.enqueue(callback)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `stormInfo` is a `List` which provides the mandatory `iterator()` and this is what you want to iterate over:

```
var cycloneList = response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.stormInfo ?: emptyList()

for (stormInfo in cycloneList) { }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Very clear answer. Thank you. I still need to figure out my JSON query, but your answer cleared it up alot. I was completely misunderstanding what the IDE was asking for.